# unresolved external symbol "cSocket::cSocket(void)" in function _main

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, linker

```
#ifndef _ClientSocket_H_
#define _ClientSocket_H_

#include "Includes.h"
#include "LOGMSGs.h"

class cSocket
{
public:
    cSocket();
    bool Open();
    bool Listen(char *OnIP,int OnPort);
    void Send(char *MSG, int len);
    void Recv(char *MSG,int len);
    void Close();
protected:
    SOCKET  cSock;
    const int   SndBuf;
};

#endif


#include "ClientSocket.h"


bool cSocket::Open()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err;
    if((err =WSAStartup(0x202, &wsaData)) !=0)
    {
        Error("Init WSAStartup() failed[%d].", err);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool cSocket::Listen(char *OnIP,int OnPort)
{
    if(Open())
    {
        //Create the main socket
        cSock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(cSock==INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            //WSACleanup();
            printf("Init socket() failed[%d].", err);
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Set the REUSEADDR SOCKET
        int     optval = 1;
        if(setsockopt(cSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) &optval, sizeof(optval)))
        {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            Close();
            printf("Init setsockopt() SO_REUSEADDR failed[%d].", err);
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Set the KEEPALIVE SOCKET
        optval = 1;
        if(setsockopt(cSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *) &optval, sizeof(optval)))
        {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            Close();
            printf("Init setsockopt() SO_KEEPALIVE failed[%d].", err);
            return FALSE;
        }

            // Set the SNDBUF SOCKET
        if(SndBuf)      // Non-0: pointer SNDBUG
        {
            optval = SndBuf;
            if(setsockopt(cSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *) &optval, sizeof(optval)))
            {
                int err = WSAGetLastError();
                Close();
                printf("Init setsockopt() SO_SNDBUF failed[%d].", err);
                return FALSE;
            }

            // Read the SNDBUF SOCKET
            int ret = sizeof(optval);
            if(getsockopt(cSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *) &optval, &ret) == 0)
            {
                LOGMSG("send buffer size SOCKET [%d] K.", optval/1024);
            }
        }

        SOCKADDR_IN     sin;
        memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
        sin.sin_family      = AF_INET;
        sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(OnIP);
        sin.sin_port        = htons(OnPort);
        if(bind(cSock, (LPSOCKADDR) &sin, sizeof(sin)))
        {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            Close();
            printf("Init bind() failed[%d].", err);
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Set to non-blocking mode
        unsigned long   i = 1;
        if(ioctlsocket(cSock, FIONBIO, &i))
        {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            Close();
            printf("Init ioctlsocket() failed[%d].", err);
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Listening port
        if(listen(cSock, SOMAXCONN))        // SOMAXCONN: WIN macro definition
        {
            int err = WSAGetLastError();
            Close();
            printf("Init listen() failed[%d].", err);
            return FALSE;
        }
        return true;
    }
return false;
}


void cSocket::Close()
{
    closesocket(cSock);
    WSACleanup();
}


#include "Includes.h"
#include "LOGMSGs.h"
#include "auth_proto.h"
#include "Packets.h"
#include "ClientSocket.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    cSocket sock;
    while(1)
    {
        sock.Open();
        sock.Listen("127.0.0.1",4444);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Error: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cSocket::cSocket(void)" (??0cSocket@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

what's wrong?

Comment: I've rolled back your changes to your question. Please leave the question with the code and everything so that if someone in the future has this same problem, they might see your question and the below answer and it may help them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a linker error, which means that the compiler has checked that the code contains no syntax errors, but the linker can't find an implementation of a function you've tried to call somewhere in the program.  In this case, the function it can't find is

```
__thiscall cSocket::cSocket(void)" (??0cSocket@@QAE@XZ)
```

This function looks cryptic because of **name-mangling**, where the compiler takes the in-source name of a function and then transforms it in a way that allows for better type-safe linking.  However, you can still see that at the code of this is the function name

```
cSocket::cSocket(void)
```

This is constructor for `cSocket`.  If you'll notice, nowhere in the code have you defined this constructor, which is why the linker can't find an implementation for it.  Modifying your code by adding an implementation should help fix this.

More generally, though, if you ever see an error like this, it usually means that you've promised the compiler that some function or object exists through a function prototype or `extern` declaration, but didn't give an object file to the linker containing its definition.  The main causes of this usually are (in roughly this order);

1. **You prototyped a function but forgot to implement it.**  That's what happened here, I think.
2. **You prototyped a function, but then implemented it with a different signature**.  For example, if you prototype a function `void MyFunction(int)` but then implement the function either as `void MyFunction(int&)` or as `void MyFunction()`, the linker will consider this an overload rather than an implementation and will give you the error at link-time rather than compile-time.
3. **You compiled code with the definition, but didn't link it in.** This could happen if you have a multi-file project and then forget to pass one of the files as input to the linker.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @templatetypedef yeah it helped alot but what if i want to not use a constructor it's keep forcing me to use it , i checked my codes and i have used every thing , and the prototypies are all good idk whats wrong :S

Comment: @MixedCoder- What do you mean by "not use a constructor?"  If you don't define a constructor for a class, C++ will automatically generate one for you that just default-initializes all of the members of the class.  Perhaps this is what you want?

Comment: @MixedCoder- I'm not sure I understand your last response - does "EXACTLY" mean "that's EXACTLY what I was looking for?"  Can you be a bit more specific with what I can help you with?  I'd like to help, but I don't think I fully understand what problems you're running into.

Comment: @templatetypedef- if i didnt use a constructor it will ask me to make one if i tried to make one it says `IntelliSense: "cSocket::cSocket()" provides no initializer for:` , if i used an empty constructor it will give me the above Error

Comment: @MixedCoder- AH!  I think I see the problem.  Your class has a `const` data member in it (`const int SndBuf`).  If you have a const data member, you must initialize it in a member initialization list inside of a constructor.  Your options would then be either to get rid of the `const` qualifier here, or to define a constructor that sets the value using something like this: `cSocket::cSocket(int value) : SndBuf(value) { ... }`.  Notice that you **must** use the member initialization list to set this value up if you leave it as a const member.

Comment: @template you said it much better than I did :)  and @Mixed, so did it compile?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't declare a constructor definition

```
cSocket::cSocket()
{
    //your init code here
}
```

if you didn't intend to have a constructor then just remove the line `cSocket();` from your class declaration

Comment: i did that and that what i got : Error C2512: 'cSocket' : no appropriate default constructor available